# How can I make a text underline appear above another element in React?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to make an underline of the selected tab be above the horizontal line, something like this: [image]

However, I'm only getting this:

[image]

I think using border will not fix the problem, since the more distant of the text I put it, the more the hr tag moves down.

CSS:

```css
.chart-area-tabs .currentTab {
    font-weight: 600;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
```

JSX:

```
<div className='chart-area-tabs'>
    <p className="currentTab">Sales (0$)</p>
    <p>Order Volume (0)</p>
    <p>Ticket Size ($0.00)</p>
</div>

<hr style={{width: 870}}/>
```

How can I correct this code?

Comment: we will need to see how your JSX or HTML looks like.. please provide more code

Comment: It would appear that the element you're styling is the entire "tab" and not just the text element within that "tab".  (Or the other way around?  It's not entirely clear to me.  A [mcve] which demonstrates would be more clear.)  You are encouraged to take a look at your HTML and see the actual structure of your elements that you're trying to style.

Comment: This is a CSS question at its core and should be presented as rendered HTML and CSS. You can put them in a demo using the editor.

Comment: What does `{this.setTabClass('sales')` do?

Comment: Please don't make meaningless edits; all your edit did was move some words around.

Comment: @TylerH, what can I do to correct my question format? Please I really need help with this

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using a simple flex-box, padded tabs, and borders instead of an `<hr>` tag.  I don't think the `<hr>` is the way to go here, since to get your desired UI you would need to overlap some other element on top of the `<hr>`, which seems unnecessarily difficult.

```css
.chart-area-tabs{
  border-radius: 16px 16px 0px 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
  
}

p{
  height: 60px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid lightgrey;
  text-align: center;
}

.filler{
   flex: 1;
}

.currentTab{
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="chart-area-tabs">
  <p>
    Sales (0$)
  </p>
  <p class="currentTab">
    Order Volume (0)
  </p>
  <p>
    Ticket Size ($0.00)
  </p>
  <p class="filler">

  </p>
    
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is that I want the tabs to remain at the left but the line to cover all of the box.

Comment: I edited my answer to include a `filler` tab to consume any extra remaining space in the row

Answer (score 0):

You should remove padding/margin around tab items. **And then add to each tab padding**. After that you will be able to add border-bottom for active tab.[example how to add paddings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMF6t.png)

Comment: Remove and then add again?!?

Comment: So now you have all your tabs in container with padding or margin around them. 

You need to remove this padding/margin and add padding for each tab item, not one padding around all tabs.

Comment: remove padding/margin from .chart-area-tabs class.

add padding to your each tab e.x.: .tab-class { padding: 10px 0 }

also replace your <hr> tag, just on border-bottom for .chart-area-tabs

Comment: I only have padding on the "<p>", not on the group of the three "<p>" @Mykola

Comment: About giving border bottom instead of hr tag, that does not go until the end of the box, just until the end of the tabs.